# Cannot find a resource file that is said to be causing the error

Tags: android

This is the error: AAPT: error: resource @android:style/style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar not found.

And the **debug\AndroidManifest.xml** keeps popping up every time I try to run he project.

This is my Android Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ticwatch_1.debug"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="28"
        android:targetSdkVersion="29" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.NavigationDrawerTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation_drawer_test"
            android:theme="@style/@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />
        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.floating_action_button"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_floating_action_button" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.drawer_activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drawer_activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.stop_pump"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_stop_pump" /> <!-- <activity -->
        <!-- android:name=".settings_for_dummy" -->
        <!-- android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_for_dummy" /> -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.CounterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_counter" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.navigation_drawer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation_drawer" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.Main_menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.tool2mode4"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tool2mode4" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.tool2mode3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tool2mode3" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.tool2mode2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tool2mode2" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.tool2mode1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tool2mode1" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.tool1mode4"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tool1mode4" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.tool1mode3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tool1mode3" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.tool1mode2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tool1mode2" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.tool1mode1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tool1mode1" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.MainActivity6"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main6" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.MainActivity5"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main5" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.MainActivity4"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main4" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.MainActivity3"
            android:label="MiLINK V4" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ticwatch_1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

These tags are the one highlighted in red:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my strings.xml file:

```
 <resources>
    <string name="app_name">TicWatch_1</string>
    <!--
    This string is used for square devices and overridden by hello_world in
    values-round/strings.xml for round devices.
    -->
    <string name="hello_world">Hello Square World!</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main2">MainActivity2</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main3">MainActivity3</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main4">MainActivity4</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main5">MainActivity5</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main6">MainActivity6</string>
    <string name="title_activity_tool1mode1">tool1mode1</string>
    <string name="title_activity_tool1mode2">tool1mode2</string>
    <string name="title_activity_tool1mode3">tool1mode3</string>
    <string name="title_activity_tool1mode4">tool1mode4</string>
    <string name="title_activity_tool2mode1">tool2mode1</string>
    <string name="title_activity_tool2mode2">tool2mode2</string>
    <string name="title_activity_tool2mode3">tool2mode3</string>
    <string name="title_activity_toolmode4">toolmode4</string>
    <string name="title_activity_tool2mode4">tool2mode4</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main_menu">Main_menu</string>
    <string name="title_activity_navigation_drawer">navigation_drawer</string>
    <string name="title_activity_counter">CounterActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_settings_for_dummy">settings_for_dummy</string>
    <string name="title_activity_stop_pump">stop_pump</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main7">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="nav_header_title">Android Studio</string>
    <string name="nav_header_subtitle">android.studio@android.com</string>
    <string name="nav_header_desc">Navigation header</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>


    <string name="menu_home">Home</string>
    <string name="menu_gallery">Gallery</string>
    <string name="menu_slideshow">Slideshow</string>
    <string name="title_activity_drawer_activity">drawer_activity</string>

    <string name="Tools">Tool</string>
    <string name="Modes">Mode</string>
    <string name="Keys">Key</string>
    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
    <string name="title_activity_floating_action_button">floating_action_button</string>
    <string name="title_activity_navigation_drawer_test">NavigationDrawerTest</string>


</resources>
```

I don't know where NavigationDrawerTest is I thought it was deleted or something like that because I couldn't find it anywhere. I was going to make it but don't remember if I canceled the process or not, but I can't find it with the other activities. I only have an activity called navigation_drawer, but that one was from before.

Comment: I believe the project is a bit old and you modified the sdk and target to 28 and 29?

Comment: Well the project was made 1 month ago, but putting that aside  if I were to change the sdk which I don't remember touching, how do I fix this? Do I do this in the build.gradle file or somewhere else?